# VPN Connectivity

Tags: networking, vpn

My office has VPN connectivity with client network which allows us to access internal applications at client side.

My company is setting up another office in different location for which we need similar connectivity to client network.

Now the problem is that client has constraint that they can provide only 1 VPN access.

Please someone let me know is it possible to do some network setup which allows accessing client applications from our new office.

1. Current situation:

office1 ---VPN---> client network

2. Requirement:

office2 ------> office1---VPN---> client network

Request you to please provide some pointers/ approaches which can be tried. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the vpn server is located in your office or the client?
it may be necessary to install a vpn server on the new client in order to avoid hacks and a single point of failure.

Comment: VPN server is located at client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by running

- a **VPN client** in your site `office1` (connected to the `client network` VPN server) and
- a **VPN server** in your site `office1` and
- a **VPN client** in your site `office2` (connected to your server in `office1`)

Depending on your network and VPN setup you need to create certain routing rules or bridging configuration in your site `office1` to connect those 2 VPN tunnels together.

If you decide to use a routed setup, you need to make sure, that you use different IP subnets in each of your sites and your VPN solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Quite the obvious answer, but I'll drop it here just in case it helps.

This mainly depends on the kind of work you do for your client and the networking load you can handle at your office but there's always the option of connecting to `office1` from `office2` over `ssh` and then to `client`.